# Why is my website being redirected to example.com?

Tags: .htaccess, ftp

Please help me! I edited the htaccess to redirect to example.com after I found a solution to a problem, so I put it in relizing my mistake then I took it out. Even though I have changed it back it now redirects my version of the site without the `www` to example.com.

Comment: Add you htaccess code...

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide your .htaccess so that we can help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more than one .htaccess?

Also, try to use another browser and you can also try to clear browser cache.